# preloading images not working on dsi

Tags: javascript, jquery, portable-applications

I have made a script that preloads a sprite sheet for using in [this](http://scratch.mit.edu/forums/viewtopic.php?pid=808209#p808209) with CSS sprites, but doesn't show up on the dsi.

Here is [my current revision](http://www.mdn.fm/files/317708_mbhb5/index.html).

Please tell me where I have gone wrong. Or suggest an easier way to preload images... But after it has loaded, a callback is called. A jQuery plugin or javascript library or something... lol. It works in Chrome... but not on the dsi...

EDIT: Fixed! See below:

Comment: What doesn't work - what is the error message if any?

Comment: There aren't any error messages; It gets stuck on the loading screen; works fine in chrome...

Comment: You need to assign .onload before you change the source I beleive

Comment: `var image = new Image();
            image.src = url;
            image.onload = function () {
                $('#topscreen').css('backgroundImage', 'url(' + url + ')');
            }` works...

Comment: it isn't a large script. You can 'debug' it easily with commenting/uncommenting lines of code and test it.

Comment: Hmm... I tried css sprites... they were white.

Comment: Whoops... Didn't link to css sprites properly XD!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just linked to the sprites improperly. XD!
If anyone else is having trouble loading images on the DSi, use css sprites!